# WPF DataGrid - Can't Use Mouse To Scroll Because Of Drag Drop

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid, prism

I am using a datagrid that is allowing to drag its rows. My problem is that when i try to scroll down on my grid using the mouse on the side scroller, i get the 'no enterance' sign that means that "drag and drop is not allowed here, dude...". How can i modify my drag and drop function to recognize that this is not a drag and drop action, but a scroll mouse action?

```
private new void MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            Point currentPosition = e.GetPosition(GridUC);

            Object selectedItem = GridUC.SelectedItem;

            if (selectedItem == null) return;

            DragDropContainerObject ddObject = new DragDropContainerObject(typeof(Actor), selectedItem);

            DataGridRow container = (DataGridRow)GridUC.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(selectedItem);

            if (container != null)
            {
                DragDropEffects finalDropEffect = DragDrop.DoDragDrop(container, ddObject, DragDropEffects.Link);
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not a single answer...

I guess im doing something really wrong here...

Anyhow, i just switched to use Telerik drag and drop functionality and forgot from this problem...